# Rails Cucumber cant run a single test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

I have been writing test for a old project using Cucumber. When I run the test sweet using the `Cucumber` command there is no problem but when I do `cucumber features/users/signup.feature` I get a message to implement the steps definitions.

**You can implement step definitions for undefined steps with these snippets:**

any ideas on what I am missing.

At this point this is not a problem but when I have more test I know this is going to be a major problem.

```
# features/users/login.feature
@javascript
  Feature: Users should be able to log in

  Scenario: User should be able to log in
    Given I am signed in as a user
    Then I should see 'Signed in successfully.'

#features/step_definitions/session_steps.rb
Given 'I am signed in as a user' do
  @user = Fabricate(:user)
  visit new_user_session_path
  fill_in 'user_email', with: @user.email
  fill_in 'user_password', with: @user.password
  click_button 'Sign In'
end
```

Comment: This could be because you may not have defined some or all the step definitions in a .rb file. You could create `signup_steps.rb` inside `features/steps` and paste the whole code snippet you get after the "You can implement..." message. If you could provide more details, then it would be easier to explain

Comment: @PhilipJohn I added my feature file and the step definition that goes with it

Comment: well it is obvious. You haven't provided a snippet in session_steps.rb for `Then I should see 'Signed in successfully.'` U will get this snippet when you run cucumber, copy and paste it and perform necessary changes for your implementation

Comment: The problem is that the test are not running. When I run all the test they all pass. the problem is when I run 1 test I get a message to implement step definitions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
cucumber features/users/signup.feature -r features/
```

Cucumber knows about a particular data structure, if you use your own data structure, you need to rely on tagging or recursively stating where your dependency files live